# Creating an automatic slideshow in angular issue

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create the following slideshow that is in plain html, css, and javascript:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_auto

I have implemented the following code, but it is not changing every two seconds as I expected to:

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { NgbCarousel, NgbSlideEvent, NgbSlideEventSource } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],

})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  role: Number;
  public selectedindex: number = 0;
  public images = ['../../assets/images/healthimage1.png', '../../assets/images/healthimage2.jpg', '../../assets/images/healthimage3.jpg'];
  
  selectImage(index: number) {
    console.log("Index: " + index);
    this.selectedindex = index;
    console.log("Selected Index: " + this.selectedindex);
  }

  showSlides() {
    let i;
    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      (<HTMLElement>slides[i]).style.display = "none";
    }
    this.selectedindex++;
    if (this.selectedindex > slides.length) { this.selectedindex = 1 }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    (<HTMLElement>slides[this.selectedindex - 1]).style.display = "block";
    dots[this.selectedindex - 1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(this.showSlides, 2000);
  }


  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) {
    this.role = 1;

  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.showSlides();
  }

}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="images">
  <div class="mySlides slideshow-container">
      <img *ngFor="let image of images; let i=index" 
          [src]="image" 
          [ngClass]="{'image-active': selectedindex == i}">  

      <div style="text-align:center; display:inline-block;"  *ngFor="let dot of images; let i=index">
          <span class="dot" 
              (click)="selectImage(i)"
              [ngClass]="{'active': selectedindex == i}">
          </span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  text-align:center;
}

.slideshow-container img{
  display: none;
}

.slideshow-container img.image-active {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

/* The dots/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how could I fix this issue? I am still learning about angular, so I may not fully understand it. Before I was using `ngb-carousel`, but I ran into some issue where I had to remove `materialize.min.css`, it limited the html that I wanted to use and now I have to change it to it a different way.

**UPDATE:** I forgot to call it, but when I do call it on `ngInit()`, I get an error that says

> Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

It does not accept `slides[this.selectedindex - 1].style.display` in typescript. So I added `(<HtmlElement>...)` but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `setTimeout(this.showSlides, 2000);` could be the cause as it "unbinds" `this` from the method.

Try `setTimeout(() => this.showSlides(), 2000)`.

However, it's best not manipulate DOM directly in angular, maybe you should find some other way (using template bindings to show the slides and observables to handle the intervals).

EDIT: Also, I don't see `showSlides()` being called from anywhere for the first time, is it called from somewhere external?

Comment: I am sorry I do not know how to call it. I thought it was `ngOnInit() { this.showSlides(); }`, but it dissappeared. How to call it?

Comment: ok I found another issue that is why it does not show. It says `Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`. It cannot read style.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manipulate the html items to make the transition. just do it like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.playSlide();
  }

  async playSlide(){
    for (let i = 0; i < this.images.length; i++) {
      await this.delay(5000); // Aguarda 5 segundo (5000 milissegundos)
      this.selectImage(i);
    }
    this.playSlide()
  }

  delay(ms: number) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
```